# WP Query - Posts Per Page not working in combination with category__in

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop

I'm not sure whether it's a bug or i'm doing something wrong, but it doesn't seem like `posts_per_page` works at all when using `category__in`.

My query is below, even though I've set `posts_per_page` to `1`, it's still showing all posts.

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__not_in'   => array($post->ID)
));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wordpress has a setting for this, found in the admin area under SETTINGS -> READING -> Blog pages show at most

You can use this instead of custom-modifying your queries. It may make it a little easier to maintain your project down the road.

Comment: @vikrantzilpe It's a custom query, which is getting only one post - I'm pretty sure that setting global post count isn't a solution in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am testing your code on my dev site and it returns only 1 result (although there are 3 items in the same category), so your code seems to be fine, maybe there is some other filter applied which ignores the posts_per_page param.

You can try using `suppress_filters => true` param in your WP_Query args list or use the get_posts() function instead of WP_Query as the function has supress_filters enabled by default so the code would be

`$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__not_in'   => array($post->ID)
));`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was modifying the limit via `pre_get_posts` elsewhere. I updated that to only affect the main query using `$query->is_main_query()`.

Comment: Sure, no problem :).